# Resources for learning Lisp

Tags: lisp

What is a good book or tutorial to learn Lisp?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) is an awesome (and free) book for anyone interested in the language.

Answer (score 5):

If you like learning by writing games "Land of Lisp" is now available, see http://landoflisp.com

Comment: I have not read the book yet but the web site is great. Contains a promotional comic and a music video. Not your typical programming book it seems.

Comment: I found this title a bit trite when I last tried to read through it, so am not as sure about it. May have just been having a bad week though.

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start off would be the [ANSI Common Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/acl.html) by Paul Graham which is what I'm hooked onto right now :)

**EDIT:** As mentioned by [spacemanaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352061/spacemanaki) "there a few areas where Graham's coding style should not be considered typical" and are listed [here](http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/325/readings/graham/graham-notes.html).

Comment: ANSI Common Lisp is indeed quite good, however it's obligatory to link to this page which outlines some of the quirks in his style: http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/325/readings/graham/graham-notes.html

Answer (score 2):

[Lisp (3rd Ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201083191) by Winston and Horn is actually a pretty good textbook. I picked it up for a steal (plenty of $2 used copies on Amazon) and I've found it to be a decent learning tool. it is sometimes easier to read than *ANSI Common Lisp* by Paul Graham, although some of the advanced stuff is a bit weird or out-of-date.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever look for at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best books for a beginner to learn Lisp by David S. Touretzky: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/