# Common Lisp: How to choose the package a symbol belongs to in the read function

Tags: common-lisp

This seems to be a very simple question, but I am still a beginner in common lisp.
I tried to load files like the following.  Without packages the symbols `'year`
`'month` etc. can be compared to in every file.

```
;;; file db.lisp
((year 2010
    (month 5
        (1 100 "A")
        (2  -5 "B"))
    (balance 10)
    (month 6
        (1  -7 "C")
        (2  -8 "D")))
(load-from-csv-format-1 "db2011.csv")
(load-from-csv-format-2 "db2012.csv"))
```

I managed to convert the existing lisp code the following

```
(defpackage :db
    (:use :common-lisp :db.csv-format-1))
(in-package :db)

(defun read-db ()
  (let ((db (with-open-file (stream "db.lisp")
             (read stream))))
...
(case (car x)
    (year (expand-year x))
    (load-from-csv-format-1 (load-format-csv-format-1-impl (second x)))
    (load-from-csv-format-2 (load-format-csv-format-1-impl (second x)))
...
```

Now all symbols belong to the package `:db`.  This has one disadvantage for me, as
all calls to `read-db` have to be done from within `:db`.  If I now want to separate
all the different csv-formats in different packages, it doesn't work anymore, since
e.g. `'balance` below belongs to the `db.csv-format-1` package which cannot be compared
against the `db::balance` symbol.

```
(defpackage :db.csv-format-1
    (:use :common-lisp)
    (:export :load-from-csv-format-1-impl))
(in-package :db.csv.format-1)
(defun load-format-csv-format-1-impl (path)
    (list 'balance 20))
```

So my question is, how is this done properly in lisp?  Can one specify to read somehow,
in which package to create symbols and then access these symbols somehow outside this
package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm)
[`intern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_intern.htm)s whatever it reads in
the package [`*package*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pkg.htm) so you can
do this:

```
(defun read-db ()
  (let* ((*package* (find-package #:db))
        ((db (with-open-file (stream "db.lisp")
               (read stream)))))
   ...))
```

**PS**. As a beginner, you might enjoy reading some of the books recommended in [Resources for learning Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094615/850781).

Comment: Thank you. CLHS is sometimes quite terse.

Comment: @user1660596: yw. indeed, CLHS is a reference, not a textbook. Please see PS.